# Java 8 how to remove item from arraylist with ids from array

Tags: java, arraylist, java-8

How to remove item from arraylist with ids from array. I have tried:

```
List <Group> loadedGroupList = iGroupRepository.findAll();
String [] groupIds = StringUtils.split(selectionGroupsIds, ',');

for (int i = 0 ; i < groupIds.length; i++) {
    String groupId = groupIds[i];
    loadedGroupList.removeIf(x -> x.getId() != Long.parseLong(groupId));
}
```

But I get an empty arraylist. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Your major flaw is `!=` in the condition instead of `==`. You shall remove if they are present and not when they are absent and that's the cause for *"I get an empty arraylist"*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`groupIds` is an `String` array, convert it into `List<String>` and use `contains()`

**removes `Group` from loadedGroupList if groupId is in groupIds array**

```
loadedGroupList.removeIf(x -> Arrays.asList(groupIds).contains(x.getId()));
```

**removes `Group` from loadedGroupList if groupId is not in groupIds array**

```
loadedGroupList.removeIf(x -> !Arrays.asList(groupIds).contains(x.getId()));
```

By using `java-8` streams, filter `Group` that doesn't have `id` in `String` array `groupIds`

```
List<Group> result = loadedGroupList.stream()
                                    .filter(x->!Arrays.asList(groupIds).contains(x.getId()))
                                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Sorry. I was not clear. I want to remove from loadedGroupList if groupId is not in loadedGroupList arraylist. How should I do it?

Comment: what? is this your question `I want to remove from loadedGroupList if groupId is not in groupIds array`? or

Comment: Would make more sense to create a `Set` of unique `groupIds` before your stream pipeline operation to check for `contains`.

Comment: @Deadpool. Sorry. It doesn't work. There was no filtering if I use Java 8 streams. It returns all the list. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: List<Group> filteredGroupList = loadedGroupList.stream()
                .filter(x->!Arrays.asList(groupIds).contains(x.getId()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
     log.debug("ids:" + selectionGroupsIds);
     
    
     
     filteredGroupList.forEach(x -> log.debug(x.getGroupName()));

Comment: For me your logic looks good, why not print groupId array and each group name and groupId from list to check any casesensitive @AlanBE

Comment: @Deadpool Yes, I did. I have groupId array is 2 and Group Name is xxxx  and id is 1 and yyy and id is 2. By right it should return only yyy and id 2. But I am getting both. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Can you show the Group pojo class and output of printing groupId array, update these things in post @AlanBE

Comment: Ah. I know why: My groupId array is type String but my List Id is long. That explains the error. Now I have made them the same type. Now it works. Thanks a lot @Deadpool

Comment: It would make sense to use a `Set` of IDs here. It doesn’t even complicate the code, as the IDs are long values anyway. `Set<Long> ids = Arrays.stream(selectionGroupsIds.split(",")) .map(Long::valueOf) .collect(Collectors.toSet());` and then either `loadedGroupList.removeIf(x -> ids.contains(x.getId()));` or `loadedGroupList.removeIf(x -> !ids.contains(x.getId()));`